# Presenting Review article at an International Conference

Tags: conference

Can I present my already published review article at an international conference?

Comment: We would like to see some additional content to make the question specific. Otherwise, we might vote for closing it as "too broad".

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully agree with the answer by @All.

The question is pretty "unclear". The answer is highly dependent on the factors like research field, the type of conference, theme of the conference, the type of your published article, and suchlike. Here one more question is there:

**Is it your own review article that has been published?**

IF

the answer to the above question is **NO**, THEN you **CAN NOT**. (I am not sure about any existing rarity in which this didn't hold.)

ELSE

I would answer based on my own research field with positive assumption that it holds for your case as well -- That is what computer science guys do a lot of times.

You can actually publish review article as a poster (if at all the conference is okay with poster presentation). Note that a published article can not be re-published in a different venue with identical content. It would be like a small talk on the review, rather than more research oriented discussion. The Computer Science conferences are true publication venues that publishes full research articles that are citable.

AGAIN,

IF you are not from an engineering discipline like CS/Mech/Electrical, rather from a pure science stream like Physics, Biology, Chemistry, then you can actually talk (poster or PPT) about it in the conference. Try speaking with the conference chair/organiser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

The review-style presentations in conferences are normally Plenary Lectures, which are given by the eminent scientists in the field.

Of course, for publishing a review article you should be a leading author in the field. Then, it is likely to be invited for a Plenary Talk.